# Adding items to a WPF DataGrid bound to an ObservableCollection with a custom mutator in MVVM C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

This will be easiest if I first explain my code structure, then try to ask my question.

I have a base class containing some simple properties. We will call this *BaseClass*. I then have several other classes that extend *BaseClass*. Let's call these *SubClass1*, *Subclass2*, and *SubClass3*. Now I have this view model, and it contains this private member:

```
private ObservableCollection<BaseClass> objs = new ObservableCollection<BaseClass>();
```

The initializer of the view model contains something like this:

```
objs.Add(new SubClass1(attribute1, attribute2));
objs.Add(new SubClass3(attribute1, attribute2));
objs.Add(new SubClass1(attribute1, attribute2));
objs.Add(new SubClass2(attribute1, attribute2));
```

Now, in this case, I have 3 separate datagrids. I want all three to draw from *objs*, but I want one to show only objects of type *SubClass1*, one to show only objects of type *SubClass2*,and the last to show only objects of type *SubClass3*. I have successfully achieved this by creating a property for each as follows:

```
public ObservableCollection<SubClass1> SubClass1Objs
{
    get
    {
        ObservableCollection<SubClass1> subObjs = new ObseleCollection<SubClass1>();
        if (objs != null)
            foreach (BaseClass obj in objs)
                if(obj.GetType() == typeof(SubClass1))
                subObjs .Add((SubClass1)obj);
        return subObjs ;
    }
}
```

The other 2 are identical. I bind the *ItemSource* of each datagrid to their property. This all works.

The user can currently edit any item in the data grid and the changes are reflected in *objs*. However, if the user tries to add an item to the datagrid, the items are not added to objs, and rightly so; I have no mutators(setters) for my properties. This is where my issues is. I am having trouble coming up with what the mutators would look like to add a new object to the collection. Does any one have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You need three separate collection views, not collections. See ICollectionView interface and ListCollectionView class (sorry, it's hard to post links from phone)

Comment: You could use a collection view or an observable collection however you should not create a new instance of the observable collection in your property getter, it is an invitation to problems. Create a separate instance at the viewmodel level and populate it with your SubClass1 instances. Any objects added to that collection will automatically appear in the grid, and if the grid creates a new instance it will be automatically added to the collection it is bound to. Use the collection changed events to detect these changes.

Comment: @Dennis So are you saying that instead of my properties being type ObservableCollection, they should be of type ListCollectionViews?

Comment: @user469104 I can try something like that and see how well it works. I will let you know.

Comment: @user469104 I did get it working using that method. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user49104 I was able to figure it out. I will post the answer here for anyone else who needs it.

I changed the properties of my *SubClass1*, *SubClass2*, and *SubClass3* Collections to have normal more normal accessors and mutators and created a private member for each:

```
private ObservableCollection<SubClass1> _SubClass1Objs ;

public ObservableCollection<SubClass1> SubClass1Objs {
        get { if (_SubClass1Objs== null) _SubClass1Objs = new ObservableCollection<SubClass1>(); return _SubClass1Objs; }
        set { if (_SubClass1Objs!= value) { _SubClass1Objs= value; RaisePropertyChanged("SubClass1Objs"); } } 
}
```

In the initializer of my view model, set the *SubClass* data :

```
SubClass1Objs= new ObservableCollection<SubClass1>();
    if (objs != null)
        foreach (BaseClass obj in objs.Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(SubClass1)))
            SubClass1Objs.Add((SubClass1)card);;
SubClass1Objs.CollectionChanged += SubClass1Objs_CollectionChanged;
```

Then lastly, in the CollectionChanged event, I check through to make sure no objects have been added or deleted and fix up objs:

```
// Check if a card was added
foreach (SubClass1 obj in SubClass1Objs)
    if (!objs.Contains(obj))
        objs.Add(obj);

// Check if a card has been deleted
for (int i = 0; i < objs.Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(SubClass1)).Count(); ++i)
{
    BaseClass obj = objs.Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(SubClass1)).ElementAt(i);
    if (!SubClass1Objs.Contains(obj))
        objs.Remove(obj);
}
```